# What's the size limit for an array in C++?

Tags: arrays, size, boolean, limit

This crashes for some reason whenever the limit is 2082192 or more.
Why, and how can I raise this limit? Does the number 2082192 ring any bells?

It seems to be a problem only on my machine - it runs fine on Ideone.com

I'm using MinGW with Code::Blocks and -std=c++11 but playing around with the settings and I haven't been able to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#define limit 2082192

int main()
{
    float time_start = clock();
    bool bucket[limit];
    float root = sqrt(limit);

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= limit; ++i)
        bucket[i] = true;

    for (unsigned int i = 2; i <= root; ++i)
        for (unsigned int j = i*2; j <= limit; j+=i)
            bucket[j] = false;

    unsigned int primes = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 2; i <= limit; ++i)
        if (bucket[i] == true)
            ++primes;

    float time_taken = clock() - time_start;

    std::cout << "Primes found: " << primes << " up to " << limit << " in " << time_taken;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The limit will be determined by the size of your stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem must be in limited stack size.

On Linux you can fix it typing

```
$ ulimit -s unlimited
```

in the terminal where you call this program from.

On Windows you may adjust stack size using `-Wl,--stack=67108864` compilation flag, where the number is expected size in bytes.